# (How) can I open the dev tools in the Microsoft Teams desktop client?

Tags: electron, microsoft-teams

I thought I had recently seen a developer open the dev tools from inside the Microsoft Teams desktop client (for Windows), but I can't easily replicate that.

Shortcuts like

<kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,

<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

don't work.

The reason I am not just using the browser version is that the same app behaves differently in browser and desktop version which makes these dev tools kind of necessary for debugging.

Comment: We will add an official way of doing it, but there's an undocumented way to do it that I can't post publicly but I'll send by email - billbl@microsoft.com.

Answer (score 42):

Install teams Desktop. Official Link given below,

https://products.office.com/en-in/microsoft-teams/download-app

If Dev mode is enabled, Right-click the Teams tray icon and choose Open Dev Tools.

Else, Enable Dev Mode by following below steps,

- Open Show hidden items to see the Teams tray icon
- Click Teams tray icon 7 times. (Normal left click)
- Now right click the Teams icon and you'll see all Dev options.

Update:

Now a new menu called DevTools opens as shown in image. Previously lot of dev options will show directly.

[image: After clicking]

Comment: On MAC, just clicking the icon in the tray 7 times and "Develop" menu shows up in menu bar. Ridiculous.

Comment: What does "Open Show hidden items" refer to? (EDIT: Ah, it's the Notification area disclosure arrow - I had that disabled so all icons are visible at all times)

Comment: For those that still don't understand this answer: The Teams icon in the System Tray of Windows, click this icon 7 times. Then after right clicking it the options will show up.

Comment: As of 2024 in the new Teams, this (hidden) functionality seems to be removed, follow [this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77848200).

Answer (score 12):

Here's the piece of code that adds the developer menus to microsoft teams:

```
trayDockMenuClickedDebugModeCheck() {
    if (this.isDebugModeEnabled() || appConfig.getInstance().getSetting(constants.settings.debugMenuDisabled)) {
        return;
    }
    this.debugMenuClickCount++;
    if (this.debugModeClickTimer) {
        clearTimeout(this.debugModeClickTimer);
        this.debugModeClickTimer = null;
    }
    if (this.debugMenuClickCount >= 4) {
        this.loggingService.logInfo('Enabling debug mode. Click count:' + this.debugMenuClickCount);
        this.debugModeEnabled = true;
        this.eventingService.emit(constants.events.debug.debugModeToggle);
    }
    else {
        this.debugModeClickTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.debugMenuClickCount = 0;
        }, constants.timeInMiliseconds.second * 30);
    }
}
```

Basically you have to click fast 4 times or more in the tray icon.

Answer (score 6):

For linux users, the process is completely different. You need to click on **`Open`** button multiple times.

Once it's done, you'll see something like [image: this]

**Source**

```js
click: () => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    yield this.restoreWindow();
    // **Enable dev menu by clicking multiple times on Open for linux as electron does not report click events from tray icon**
    if (utility.isLinux() && this.trayAppIcon) {
        AppStateService.getInstance().trayDockMenuClickedDebugModeCheck();
        if (AppStateService.getInstance().isDebugModeEnabled() && !this.isDebugMenuSetUp) {
            this.buildContextMenu();
            this.trayAppIcon.setContextMenu(this.contextMenu);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Teams tray icon context menu]

Right-click the Teams tray icon and choose **Open DevTools**. **This is available only in the Developer build of Teams.** See [this Microsoft doc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-tools)

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a way to do it with the new teams:

1. Create a configuration.json file under:
   %localappdata%\Packages\MSTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Microsoft\MSTeams
2. In the file add: `{"core/devMenuEnabled": true}` Restart the client.
3. Right click the Teams client icon in system tray to see the
4. Engineering Tools entry point.

[image]

Credit: https://thechriskent.com/2023/11/02/enabling-dev-tools-in-the-new-microsoft-teams-client/

Original answer on Microsoft blog: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/announcing-general-availability-of-the-new-microsoft-teams-app/bc-p/3947306/highlight/true#M13303