# UI Automation fails to find elements in Microsoft Teams . . . UNLESS. . . Inspect.exe was used prior to inspect elements

Tags: vb.net, microsoft-teams, ui-automation

When using the managed UI Automation, I cannot get the elements automatically from MS Teams.  I am assuming there HAS to be a method to launch Teams or a flag to set that allows accessibility to be utilized.  If I run Inspect.exe FIRST, and then try my code below, the commented line for `CalendarButton` works FLAWLESSLY.  If I DO NOT run Inspect.exe then the for Loop I was hoping would iterate all buttons fails to enumerate ANYTHING!!!  I've scoured MSDN and the internet wide over and cannot find anything relating on how to develop something that will enable those features.

Anyone have any ideas?  Like I said - the code below worked flawlessly (without the need for the for loop and using only the commented lines to find the calendar button.)

### Edit

I have found out that since Teams is ALSO based on Chromium, if you run it from command line with `--force-renderer-accessibility` it will allow enumeration, but you MUST kill all existing MSTeams sessions for it to work.  (I have to give partial credit to [this SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678907/how-can-i-open-the-dev-tools-in-the-microsoft-teams-desktop-client) as it allowed me to open a dev side of Teams to see this flag is available (see image below code sample).  Although this is "nice" to know, it's not getting at the *root* of my question (albeit, I'll still probably use this).  What I'm actively looking for is ***HOW*** Inspect is able to trigger this accessibility feature *on demand*

```vb
  Public Shared Sub QuickTeamsTry()
    Dim MainWinds As AutomationElementCollection
    Dim TeamsMainWindow As AutomationElement
    Dim TeamsMainHandle As IntPtr
    Dim MainTeamWindow As AutomationElement
    Dim MainTeamHandle As IntPtr
    Dim ChatPanel As AutomationElement
    Dim ChatComp As AutomationElement
    Dim CalendarButton As AutomationElement

    TeamsMainHandle = WindowsEnumerator.FindWindowEx(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "Teams.exe")
    If TeamsMainHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
      MainWinds = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "pane"))
      For a = 0 To MainWinds.Count - 1
        If MainWinds(a).Current.Name.Contains("Teams, Main Window") Then
          TeamsMainWindow = MainWinds(a)
          TeamsMainHandle = MainWinds(a).Current.NativeWindowHandle
          Exit For
        End If
      Next
    Else
      TeamsMainWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(TeamsMainHandle)
    End If

    MainTeamWindow = TeamsMainWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "document"))
    If Not IsNothing(MainTeamWindow) Then MainTeamHandle = MainTeamWindow.Current.NativeWindowHandle

    Dim Buttons As AutomationElementCollection = MainTeamWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "button"))

    For a = 0 To Buttons.Count
      'Gives me index out of bounds exception at _0_!!!
      Debug.Print(Buttons(a).Current.Name)

    Next a

    'CalendarButton = MainTeamWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, New AndCondition(New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "button"),
    '                                                                                New PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Calendar Toolbar")))


    'WindowsEnumerator.SetForegroundWindow(TeamsMainHandle)
    'Click_Object(CalendarButton)
    
    'Cannot even invoke the button since it was never set
    'Dim invoker As InvokePattern = TryCast(CalendarButton.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern), InvokePattern)
    'invoker.Invoke()

  End Sub
```

[image: Accessing Chrome://accessibility from "DevTool" submenus exposed via article referenced in 1]

[image: Teams window with "Chrome Accessibility" presented. . . On a hunch based off of this window, I used --force-renderer-accessibility from CMD when launching Teams.exe and it is valid. . .]

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: No - I was not able to solve this yet outside of the kludgy workaround . . .  I still have not figured out how Inspect.exe can tell MSTeams that it's able to see the information.